# Rankings organized into sector buckets in Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have an excel file (2013) with about 100 columns and 2000 rows with data. I am looking for help with a formula that will allow me to organize in ascending order ranked tickers based on sector.

What I am looking to do is fill in a sheet with 10 sectors in the following format:

Consumer Discretionary (heading in Row 1)
Rank (column A) | Ticker (Column B) | Company Name (Column C)

Consumer Staples (heading in Row 20)
Rank (column A) | Ticker (Column B) | Company Name (Column C)

etc.

What I need is to fill in the Tickers using a formula. In the data sheet I have ticker, sector, and ranking in separate columns. And I am looking to pull in the top 20 highest ranked tickers for each sector.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It should be noted that the data is in a table format and not ordered by sector.

Comment: @pnuts I don't believe so. I am working on a separate worksheet and need to have them listed in order by sector. Unless I am simply not applying the filter correctly.

Comment: @pnuts I see what you mean. my rankings are 1-n for a list of stocks with representation from each sector in it. If I filter by "top 10" and by sector then yes I get the list I want. However, I am trying to get away from having to manually filter that way.